# Is there a way to increase the height of the strip.text bar in a facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the grey bar at the top to be wider, as in, have the edges of it a little further from the top and bottom of the letters (the strip.text - A, B, C etc). I would have thought the lineheight would have acted as padding but it doesn't.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE)+
  facet_wrap(~ color) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(lineheight=20))
```

Comment: Increasing the text size itself isn't satisfactory?

Comment: @alexwhan, increasing the text size will increase the strip size as well, but it will not change the *ratio* of the two

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, agreed - I like your solution

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, modify the levels so that they include a linebreak:

```
levels(diamonds$color) <- paste0(" \n", levels(diamonds$color) , "\n ")
```

Then adjust as necessary.   eg:

```
P <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
      xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE)+
      facet_wrap(~ color)

P +  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=9, lineheight=0.5))
```

[image: lineheight=0.5]

```
P +  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=9, lineheight=3.0))
```

[image: lineheight=3.0]

Comment: Delayed reply on my part... Thanks, a dirty solution let's be honest haha, but certainly get's the job done. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

With `ggplot2` 2.2.0, you can apply Ricardo's trick without modifying the dataframe, by using `labeller`:

```
P <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE)+
  facet_wrap(~ color, labeller = labeller(color=setNames(paste0("\n", levels(diamonds$color), "\n"), levels(diamonds$color))))

P +  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=9, lineheight=0.5))
```