# varying strip heights for multi-panel lattice plots

Tags: r, lattice

It is easy to change the default strip height for `lattice` plots: the `par.strip.text` argument is all that one needs.  But is there a simple way to to have strips of different heights within one multi-panel lattice plot?

I have in mind a plot with two rows of panels.  The height of the strips in the first row would differ from the height of the strips in the second row.

I think that I can create such a figure by creating two plots –– one for the first row, another for the second row –– and then using `grid.layout` to position them.  But I'd like to know if there is a more straightforward way to create such a figure.

Comment: I'm tempted to call this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17825201/324364) Q, even though it's a ggplot Q. That's the only method I can think of, though, and it _should_ work.

Comment: @joran -- Thanks.  But I'm interested in having strips of different heights within a single plot, and as best I can tell, that Q is about a different problem.  (I also am not sure of how I would adapt the ggplot code there for use with lattice.  I've tried just varying the `lines` element in the `par.strip.text` argument, so that `lines` varies by panel.  But that doesn't work: `lines` needs to be  a single number.)

Comment: No. You would just add different number of newline characters to each level. That's the point: adding newline characters to the actual variable levels.

Comment: So I just checked, and that method (adding newline characters) doesn't seem to have any effect in lattice. Oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified an example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8536239/324364) question (which is a much closer duplicate) and managed to achieve this:

```
bgColors <- c("black", "green4", "blue", "red", "purple", "yellow")
txtColors <- c("white", "yellow", "white", "white", "green", "red")
stripHt <- rep(c(-1,0),each = 3)

# Create a function to be passes to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
    panel.rect(0, stripHt[which.panel], 1, 1,
               col = bgColors[which.panel],
               border = 1)
    panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
               font=2,
               lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
               col = txtColors[which.panel])
}    
xyplot(yield ~ year | site, data = barley, strip=myStripStyle)
```

[image]

Ignore the horrible colors. You get the point, we're just using a custom strip function.

Comment: Quick note: `which.panel` no longer seems to work (R 3.1.3, lattice 0.20-30).  But `panel.number()` does the same.