# How can I keep my facet_wrap() plots from being squished

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This is my first time posting a question here so I'm nervous, but this has been bugging me forever: when using facet_wrap() in ggplot, is there a way to keep your plots from getting all squished when you have a lot of them? (see example below)

[image: squishy plots]

There is too much range in the data so I have to free the scales, otherwise I would set the y-axis breaks and probably have fewer labels to that from crowding. But the biggest thing is that the plots are so squished they become hard to see. When I put space in between the plots it just squishes them more as though it is working with a limited amount of space. I also tried adjusting font sizes, getting rid of the title, and even the legend. Removing the legend makes more room but obviously, that's sort of an important thing to have in there!

Is there a way to fix this or is this just something that goes with trying to facet a lot of plots?

Here is my code:

```
  lu_acres_plot <- ggplot(data = land_use_acres, aes(x = land_use, y = acres)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = land_use)) +
  facet_wrap(~i_desclu, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(title = "Land Use Change",
       y = "Change in Acreage") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = lu_pallette) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family = "Times"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
     strip.background = element_rect(color = "grey40", fill = "grey30"),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 9, color = "white", face = "bold"),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "grey40", fill = NA)
   ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Land Use",
                               title.position = "top",
                               nrow = 2))
lu_acres_plot
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how you want to make them less squished. What exactly do you want to change? You can always just make your plotting device taller so you have more room. It's not clear currently how you are saving this image. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Mayeb [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783189/changing-the-appearance-of-facet-labels-size) can help.

Comment: Try saving plot to a file and manually adjusting the plot dimensions. `ggsave("plot1.pdf", plot=lu_acres_plot, width=12, height=8)`. Change height and width until the pdf looks good to you.

Comment: @bdemarest thank you that worked beautifully! I never thought of changing the aspect ratio but that's the piece I've been missing! Thank you, this has bothered me for years!

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you that page is very helpful too!